# Silex authentication + authorization (UserProvider, SecurityServiceProvider)

Tags: php, authentication, doctrine-orm, authorization, silex

I'm currently using the Silex framework.

I was wondering which UserProviders and/or SecurityServiceProvider are out there and how they work. In my application I would work with a mysql database controlled by Doctrine dbal (or orm)

I have already found Opauth (https://github.com/icehero/silex-opauth).
But I'm wondering how I can implement this.

Can someone please explain me how this works, explain me the basic authentication + authorization workflow?

**EDIT:**

How can I use the login, logout functions in a restfull way? Are there any possibilities to also have a register function with email confirmation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look inside the docs:

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-user-provider

You have to implement `UserProviderInterface` and `UserInterface` interfaces. Inside your user provider implementation you can use doctrine to get the User records and create from the record a user class instance.

After this, add the user provider to our security provider:

```
'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
    return new UserProvider($app['db']);
}),
```

Comment: How can I use the login, logout functions in a restfull way? Are there any possibilities to also have a register function?

Comment: For register add a simple action that insert a new user in your db. For login and logout i have no idea, sry.